# Download clipped area of Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF

Tags: cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have a Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF (COG) stored at an endpoint accessible by URL. Using this URL I generate tiles using TiTiler and serve them to my front-end map application.

I would like users to be able to download a portion of the COG. I could use the existing URL endpoint and let them download the whole thing but it's really large. Is there a way to download just a portion of a COG using a bounding box? Since COGs support range requests, I thought this might be possible somehow.

Comment: There is a lot of information in https://www.cogeo.org/. I suggest to read it first and make focused questions after that, if necessary.

Comment: @user30184 - do you know the information? I feel like this is a reasonable question that someone else might have. It's more useful to share info than to just suggest people "read the docs"

Comment: GDAL (`gdal_translate` command line executable, GDAL API bindings for various languages or other software built on top of GDAL such as the `rasterio` python library) can extract by bounding box from COGs. Hard to make any recommendation without details of your back-end stack.

Comment: this is helpful.. I was hoping to avoid backend processing and just make the clip via a range request on the url